# Установка QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

Возможно в период запрета на установку QT на территории РФ всё таки как-нибудь выполнить ее, без использования VPN.

Comment: Можно установить Линукс. А там работает. А можно помочь убрать запрет, но это тема другого форума.

Comment: Запрет распространяется только на установку из онлайн-инсталлятора. Можно собрать из сорцов, доступ к коду никто не закрывал

Answer (score 1):

Для windows предлагаю использовать [`MSYS`](https://www.msys2.org/) - В пакетах есть как `Qt5`/`Qt6` так и свежий `QtCreator`

```bash
$ pacman -Suy mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5-base
$ pacman -Suy mingw-w64-x86_64-qt6-base
$ pacman -Suy mingw-w64-x86_64-qt-creator
```

Для Linux - `Qt5`/`Qt6` доступны из репозиториев.(`QtCreator` свежей версии можно с [GitHub](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator) скачать)

Общий способ - собирать из исходников. Для упрощения сборки использовать пакетные менеджеры - [`vcpkg`](https://vcpkg.io/en/)/[`conan`](https://conan.io/)

Answer (score 0):

скачивается offline инсталятор. Потом отключается интернет и спокойно устанавливается среда и библиотека

Comment: Скиньте ссылку на  offline инсталятор, пожалуйста

Comment: http://dt.digitser.cn/en-US/download/qt.html

Comment: Заодно хороший повод освежить знания китайского языка

Comment: Он тоже вроде просит вход в аккаунт

Comment: @eri, да, просит, но можно небыстро скачать через tor browser, интересно можно ли online installer через tor proxy заставить работать?..

Answer (score 0):

Почему не хотите использовать VPN? Это же проще.

1. Заходите на [сайт](https://login.qt.io/login) и регистрируетесь.
2. Далее идете на [другой сайт](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source) и скачиваете *online installer*.
3. Включаете *любой VPN* на ПК и заходите в этот установщик.
4. Далее входите в аккаунт, который регистрировали по ссылке №1.
5. Ура, дальше выбираем *компоненты* и ждем завершения установки.